# Is this the right way to go about proving this? $\lim_{x\to-3}((x+3)/(x^2-9))=1/6$

Tags: limits, proof-verification

$$\lim_{x \to -3} \frac{x+3}{x^2-9}$$

Suppose the limit is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=min(1,-7(\frac{1}{6}-\epsilon),(7(\frac{1}{6}+\epsilon))$

Then $7(\frac{1}{6}-\epsilon)<x+3<7(\frac{1}{6}+\epsilon)$.

So $\frac{1}{6}-\epsilon<\frac{x+3}{7}<\frac{1}{6}+\epsilon$

Then $-\epsilon<\frac{x+3}{7}-\frac{1}{6}<\epsilon$

Which is equivalent to $|\frac{x+3}{7}-\frac{1}{6}|<\epsilon$

Since $\delta<1$, $|x+3|<1$ means $|x^2-9|<7$,

so $|\frac{x+3}{x^2-9}-\frac{1}{6}|<\epsilon$.

Comment: The last step is a little confusing to me: it seems that if the thing inside the absolute value bars is very very close to $\varepsilon$, you might screw things up by making it larger (which is what happens when you replace a denominator in a positive term with something smaller). On the other hand, it might be fine, but you'd need to convince me.

Comment: You need a few steps between 2 and three.  You use an epsilon without declaring it.  You define a delta and then never use it.  Then you make a claim about x+3 that isn't true for all x.  (What if epsilon = 0 and x= .... say 53,876?)

Comment: What if $x^2  < 9$ then you have $|x+3/x^2-9 + 1/6 | < e $.

Comment: Minor note: I think the limit is actually $-\frac16$.

Comment: If you are trying to prove the limit is $1/6$, then it is absolutely wrong to start with "Suppose the limit is $1/6$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $$\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x+3}{x^2-9} = \frac{-1}{6}$$

To see how to arrive at this we use the algebra of limits of functions.
$$\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x+3}{x^2-9} = \lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x+3}{(x-3)(x+3)} $$
We can cancel because it is not in the indeterminate form. (x is approaching -3, but not reaching it).
Therefore, $$\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x+3}{(x-3)(x+3)} = \lim_{x\to -3}\frac{1}{x-3} = \frac{-1}{6}$$

Secondly, how can you guarantee the validity of the third line? Also, $a<c$ and $b<d$ doesn't imply $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$.

P.S. My humble apologies if I have misinterpreted anything.